# MongoDB supports references from one document to another. Does DynamoDB supports the same?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, database

MongoDB supports references from one document to another.
[image]
Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Does DynamoDB also supports this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB references are not hard bound. Unlike foreign key constraint they would allow you to delete parent document even if the references are there in other document. It's a manual reference which you can maintain and use from application. However DBRef is provided by Monogo which is kind of hard bound but are strongly advised against because it limits the benefit of Mongo.

As far as manual reference goes, there is no reason why we can't use it in dynamoDB. the id of one table can be used as a field in another table. Again it won't be binding. But I don't think there is any hard bound reference system is in dynamoDB.

Mongo provides ObjectId as an inherent way to generate Ids, however you can use other types in _id field also. In dynamoDB it is more likely that you will choose an id type by yourself though you can use it's UUID feature also. But in dynamoDB you would mostly query on the primary key, so UUID won't be that helpful.